# Why this HTML works

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm trying to figure out WHY HTML code in the example below works.
The goal was to put button on the left part of the line, and to fill all existing space of the line with input element.

I found that solution

```
<html>
<body>

<style>
button {
    float: left;
}
p {
 overflow:auto;
}

input {
    width: 100%;
}

</style>

     <button>Search</button>
     <p><input type="text" title="Search" /></p>

</body>
</html>
```

As I read it.. 
button is block element with float left.. so it should be leftmost element of the line with box size enough to fit "Search" word.

`p` element is a block element, it's box should contains button's box because it is floating left.

input element has 100% width of his parent, so it should be of the width of the line. So its box should not fit on the line with button so line break should be introduced... But it doesn't and everything is working for some reason.., and I cannot figure out why. And if you remove `"overflow:auto"`, line break actually introduces...

Comment: The use of `overflow:auto` changes how it interacts with `float`ed elements.

Comment: If a block element with `overflow:auto` didn't have a reduced width to avoid floats, right floated elements would partially or entirely obscure the scrollbar, making the page difficult to use.

Answer (score 1):

its because of the float:left; and the overflow of the p tag

if you try to move the overflow to the input
the input form will be on breakline and will be 100%;

look: https://jsfiddle.net/qgykwxea/

CODE:

```
button {
    float: left;
}

input {
    width: 100%; overflow-x:auto;
}
```